# Spring boot env vaiables are not replaced in custom property file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, java-8, environment-variables

I am running a spring boot dockerized application with embedded tomcat. I have a properties file called `myconfig.properties` under resources folder

myconfig.properties

`myvariable=${ENV_MYVARIABLE}`

This file content is required during startup of app.The file is consumed by a library which is accessed during startup. Spring boot is replacing the envioronment variables under application.properties file but this env variable in `myconfig.properties` file is not replaced. The file is no where  accessed within my code. the third party library requires the file during startup and during it's execution, it reads the contents of the file.Since this env variable is not replaced, my app is not starting up. The variable is supplied as env variable to docker during `docker run`, just like other variables.Can somebody please help

FYI, if i run the springboot jar in my local machine , by setting the env vairables in terminal, the app can access the variables, if am writing as `myvariable=${env.ENV_MYVARIABLE}`. But in Docker, the app cant access

Comment: It all depends on the third party library. How does it look for the file in question. Any well-written library will allow a system property to specify where to look for the file. If the library is not customizable that way, and only looks in the classpath for the file, then you need to make sure the classpath includes a directory that contains the file.

Comment: @Andreas ,the library is reading like `ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myconfig")` . There is no system property to define the location too. So do you think, i can procced..

Comment: Of course you can proceed, you just need to make sure the classpath lists the folder or jar file containing the property files.

Comment: FYI, if i run the springboot jar in my local machine , by setting the env vairables in terminal, the app can access the variables, if am writing as `myvariable=${env.ENV_MYVARIABLE}`. But in Docker, the app cant access

Comment: Quoting the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html): *"Resource bundles contain **locale-specific** objects."* --- Property values coming from environment variables don't sound like locale-specific properties to me, so it sounds like the code is misusing resource bundles.

Comment: This app is migrated from Servlet to spring boot. The code was working fine there..

Comment: FYI, the properties file is under the folder "resources/Resource Bundle 'roles' ''

Comment: @Andreas, should i place the file outside src/ and include in classpath

Comment: The `src/resources` folder doesn't exist at runtime, if the application has been packaged into a jar file. You need to learn the difference between the directory structure of your project and the content of your application when deployed. Main thing to keep in mind: ***Source files are read-only / non-existent in a packaged application***.

Comment: Sorry to ask, am not sure where to place my properties file :(

Comment: Because, am writing to the properties file only after the jar packaging is done. i.e.only on app startup am writing